# Completing the square for a quartic expression

Tags: recreational-mathematics

By completing the square, find (for real $x$) the minimum value of:
$$x^4 + 2x^2 + 2.$$

Comment: As all terms are non-negative, the minimum must be when $x=0$... For a change completing the square seems overkill!

Comment: take $y=x^2$ and complete the square, just a tip

Answer (score 2):

$$x^4+2x^2+2=(x^2+1)^2+1$$

Now for real $x,x^2\ge0$

Answer (score 1):

We can observe that
$$x^4+2x^2\geq 0$$
for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and so,
$$x^4+2x^2+2\geq 2$$
for all $x\in \mathbb R$. Moreover, for $x=0$, we have that 
$$0^4+2\cdot 0^2+2=2$$
and so $2$ is the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

$$ x^4+x^2+2=(x^2+1)^2+1\\x^2\geq 0\\x^2+1  \geq 0+1 \\(x^2+1)^2 \geq (1)^2\\so\\(x^2+1)^2+1\geq 1+1 $$